# Add a row to a matrix in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, matrix, row

This is a very simple question but I couldn't find the answer in Google or in OpenCV documentation. How do you insert a row with either a vector or a default number at the bottom of a `cv::Mat`? I tried:

```
std::vector<double> v = {0, 0, 1};
m.push_back(v);
```

which compiles, but it always gets me an assertion error. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: please show, how the Mat looks like. yes, you can insert a row this way, but what you insert, has to look like an actual row.

Comment: The Mat looks like this: [8.4-312, 2.1e-314, 2.1e-314;
  4294967296.0, -2.3e+77, 2.8e-269]. Is it really possible to use an `std::vector`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The added element must be a `Mat` with the same number of columns as the container matrix:

```
cv::Mat m = cv::Mat::ones(4, 3, CV_64F);    // 3 cols, 4 rows
cv::Mat row = cv::Mat::ones(1, 3, CV_64F);  // 3 cols, 1 row
m.push_back(row);                           // 3 cols, 5 rows
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But I wonder why the doc says "[The `Mat::push_back` methods] emulate the corresponding method of STL vector class".

Comment: I guess it is because you can add and delete (`pop_back`) elements at the end of the matrix, being rows these elements (instead of single values), as you can do with vectors.

Comment: Ok, so that just means that `cv::Mat` has functions homologous to those of STL vectors, but does not use STL vectors as arguments. OpenCV doc ought to be a little more explicit IMO. Well, thank you!

Comment: will it still work like this if adding a column, where number of rows in both `cv::Mat` are same?

Comment: What if we want to append the entire matrix at the bottom of another matrix.

Comment: @pranavshukla Use `cv::vconcat`: http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga744f53b69f6e4f12156cdde4e76aed27

Comment: @masad `push_back` only works for adding rows.  If you want to add a column, use `cv::hconcat`: http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaf9771c991763233866bf76b5b5d1776f