# Rowwise operation of copying std::vector into cv::Mat_ of identical sizes

Tags: c++, opencv

Does push_back on cv::Mat_ automatically sorts the data contigously row wise?

I am trying to copy vector values to opencv Mat. The problem is a run time exception.

```
Error: (-215) DataType<_Tp>::type == type() && cols == 1 in function push_back
```

Code

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <opencv2/core/cvdef.h>
#include <opencv2/core/mat.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.hpp>


int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {
   cv::Mat_<float> samples_xy(2, 100);
   std::vector<float> xsamples(100,1),ysamples(100,2);
   for ( auto t : xsamples ) {
       samples_xy.push_back(t);
   }
   for ( auto t : ysamples ) {
       samples_xy.push_back(t);
   }
}
```

Comment: You should check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212597/add-a-row-to-a-matrix-in-opencv

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @BHawk for the hint and I am completing the answer here with the correct code.

```
Error: (-215) DataType<_Tp>::type == type() && cols == 1 in function push_back
```

This is the explanation of the error .

Its not possible to push_back upon a cv::Mat family with any other type other than cv::Mat family  ( Mat, Mat_, Matx ). In the question, I am trying to push a float and its not allowed.

The other problem  is that the number of columns must be the same as the matrix where the item is being pushed to. So any other Mat with the same number of columns must be pushed. In the above case, only matrices with 100 columns can be pushed.

So, the entire code looks like this -

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <opencv2/core/cvdef.h>
#include <opencv2/core/mat.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.hpp>


int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {

    cv::Mat_<float> samples_xy;

    // fill the row of both the mats with 1 and 2 respectively.

    cv::Mat_<float> xsamples(1, 100, 1.f), ysamples(1, 100, 2.f);

    samples_xy.push_back(xsamples);
    samples_xy.push_back(ysamples);

    std::cout << samples_xy;
}
```